# Running a URL without opening browser via CMD on a loop

Tags: windows, cmd

I'd like to be able to effectively "run" a URL which updates a website once per minute via the command line. Is this possible and if so how can I do it?

I do not want this command to open a browser, so "start" will not work. I just want it to run the same url once per minute.

Comment: [wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) or [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/)

Comment: That's for linux @fvu and you can't assume the OP has [**_Cygwin_**](http://cygwin.com/) on their computer

Comment: @AP. Absolutely not. [curl exists in a bazillion precompiled binary versions, including windos without cygwin](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html). And [wget too](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm). Don't spread misinformation.

Comment: I take that back, fvu however, it still relies on non-native binaries to get the Job done. (_which the OP may not necessarily be averse to_)

Comment: I assume that by "non native binaries" you actually mean "binaries that are not present on the MS distribution CD". I've never seen a Windows system older than 10 minutes that only contained "native binaries" (sic) :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 7 or above, you have access to PowerShell in your shell. Now although there might be more efficient solutions using command utilities like `curl` and `wget`. You can simply do the following in your batch file:

```
:: Use the Out-Null under if you want to suppress output from server response
echo Updating server...
powershell -NoProfile "irm <YOUR_URL here> | Out-Null"
```

A complete implementation might look like

```
@echo off

:PingServer
  echo Updating Server...
  call powershell -NoProfile "irm <YOUR_URL here> | Out-Null"
  ping localhost -n 60 -w 1000 > NUL
goto PingServer
```

***Note:*** Ping is used as a `second` based sleep mechanism, since `timeout`/`sleep` is not available in all windows environments.

A complete PowerShell approach might look like:

```
$URL = "<your url>"

# Update the server, and additional processing if you'd want
function Update-Server {
    Write-Host "Updating the server..."
    irm $URL | Out-Null
}

# While loop to update server, then sleep 1 minute
while(1) {Update-Server;sleep 60}
```

Comment: how would you make this run on a loop - ie once per minute?

Comment: Added implementation

Comment: @AP. and why do you use ping for your timing? `sleep 60` is native, and will pause the batchfile for 60 seconds.

Comment: @fvu It's not part of windows 7 by itself, and requires the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en), you can refer to the [How do I make a batch file wait / sleep for some seconds?](https://superuser.com/questions/48231/how-do-i-make-a-batch-file-wait-sleep-for-some-seconds) question on SuperUser StackExchange.